# Summarizing (Statistics_analysis) with field list in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, summarizing

I want to summarize a field in 5th order in the shapefile. For that reason, I write a script below

```
output_lines = r"C:\Outputs\lines.shp"
sum_table = r"C:\Outputs\summary.dbf"

Listfield = arcpy.ListFields(output_lines)

for field in Listfield:
        arcpy.Statistics_analysis(output_lines, sum_table, [["Total_Leng", "SUM"]], field[5])
```

I get the error which is "TypeError: 'Field' object does not support indexing". I'm using ArcMap 10.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ListFields is a list of your fields, so don't loop on it but go directly to the field in the 5th order (which is field number 4 because Python indices start at 0). Furthermore, listfields is a list of fields and not a list of fields name, so you need to use field names:

```
arcpy.Statistics_analysis(output_lines, sum_table, ["Total_Leng", "SUM"], List_of_fields[4].name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting an index on the field object. ([5]) is the index you set.  You shouldn't do this if you are using a for loop already.  I believe if you just remove the [5] it will work just fine.

If you want the 5th field, you can just use Listfield[5] in place of field[5].